# Searching a string inside an array of two Hashes

Tags: ruby

I wrote the following:

```
Tab = [{"quiche"=>{"pepper"=>"10gr","cheeze"=>"50gr"}},{"pizza"=>{"tomato"=>"80gr","cheese"=>"100gr"}}]
```

which is an array of two hashes, each of which contains a hash. I want to know if there is a `pizza` recipe in the array. The only thing I found was to do so:

```
Tab.each {|meal| meal.each{|key,val| puts key}}
quiche
pizza
```

Then I can make a test to know if the key is the value I'm looking for. But I'm pretty sure this is a dirty way of doing it.

I tried to apply some methods like: `Tab.include?("pizza")`, but it returns `false` every time because it is looking into the two elements inside `Tab`:

```
{"quiche"=>{"pepper"=>"10gr", "cheeze"=>"50gr"}}
{"pizza"=>{"tomato"=>"80gr", "cheese"=>"100gr"}}
```

and `{"quiche"=>{"pepper"=>"10gr", "cheeze"=>"50gr"}}` is not `"quiche"`. Someone help me, please. I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the ruby docs the very useful things for this problem are listed in the Enumerable class.  Depending on how strict you want to be about finding it you have a few options, but

```
Tab.any?{|recipe| recipe.keys.include?("pizza")}
```

should work.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your quick answer. I'm going to check this right now.

Ps: I don't know why, I can't add any hello all! at the begining of my topic.. it disappears everytime I edit! ..

Comment: Yes it perfectly does what I am looking for... I'm so ashamed it is so simple.. I tried so many things much more complicated... Well thanks a lot and sorry for this dumb question! :) Have a nice evening.

Comment: @Oulanos Greetings are automatically removed.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989

Comment: Nice; there are so many ways to do things in Ruby!  I used Tab.select{|recipe| recipe.include? "pizza"}  This returns all of the matches as a new array.  If you just want a found/not found answer though James' answer is simpler.

Comment: Yes that was the purpose of my tests. But I also take your answer for some other purposes :) thanks @bigtunacan

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci How is mine? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the methods - [`Hash#assoc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-assoc) or [`Hash#has_key?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F)

```
Tab = [{"quiche"=>{"pepper"=>"10gr","cheeze"=>"50gr"}},{"pizza"=>{"tomato"=>"80gr","cheese"=>"100gr"}}]

Tab.any? {|h| h.assoc("pizza") } #=> true
Tab.any? {|h| h.has_key?("pizza") } #=> true
```

Comment: `has_key?` is nice.  I often find myself using `keys.include?` and should switch.   Since you're just throwing away the key and value assoc doesn't make sense here.  `Tab.any? {|h| h["pizza"]}` seems better, but I suppose it depends on how one wants to handle nil or false values.